# how to return string requested in url?

Tags: node.js

How do you get the get request string into a viable, like if someone goes to www.mypage.com/yo , how can I get node to return "yo" into a variable?

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  var stringrequested = ??????
  response.end(stringrequested);

});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.url` contains the requested uri:

```
var stringrqeuested = request.url; // /yo
```

If you want just the "yo", you can remove the leading slash like this:

```
var stringrqeuested = request.url.substr(1); // yo
```

But `request.url` contains also the query string e.g. `/yo?a=b&c=d`. If you don't want that, you'll need to parse the url:

```
var stringrequested = require('url').parse(request.url).pathname; // /yo
var stringrequested = require('url').parse(request.url).pathname.substr(1); // yo
```

Here is an example from the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url).

```
node> require('url').parse('/status?name=ryan', true)
{ href: '/status?name=ryan',
  search: '?name=ryan',
  query: { name: 'ryan' },
  pathname: '/status' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cut off the first character of the URL (`/`):

```
request.url.substr(1)
```